# How to solve for an unknown variable

Tags: optimization

For the following, I do not understand how to solve for $d$

**Problem Statement:**

Choose $\mathbf{c}$ and $d$ to minimize $MSE=E(|y_k-a_{k-d}|^2)= E(|\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{r}_k-a_{k-d}|^2)$

where $d\in\mathbb Z^+_0$ and $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$. Also $a_k$ are iid that means $E(a_ka_i)=0\forall i\neq k$ and $E(a_k^2)=E_a$

**Solution:** $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{p}$

is obtained for a given $d$

\begin{align}
MSE &= E(|y_k-a_{k-d}|^2) \\
    &= E(|\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{r}_k-a_{k-d}|^2)\\
    &= \mathbf{c}^TE(\mathbf{r}_k^{}\mathbf{r}_k^T)\mathbf{c} + E(|a_{k-d}|^2) - 2\mathtt{Re}\{\mathbf{c}^TE(\mathbf{r}_ka_{k-d})\} \\
    &= \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{R}\mathbf{c} + E_a - 2\mathtt{Re}\{\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{p})\}\\
    &= (\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{p})^T\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{p})+E_a-\mathbf{p}^{T}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{p}\tag{1}
\end{align}

where

1. $\mathbf{R}=E(\mathbf{r}_k\mathbf{r}_k^T)$
2. $\mathbf{p}=E(\mathbf{r}_ka_{k-d})$
3. $\mathbf{r}_k = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{a}_k+\mathbf{n}_k$
4. $\mathbf{H} = [\mathbf{h}_0 \mathbf{h}_1 \cdots \mathbf{h}_d \cdots \mathbf{h}_{N+\mu}]$ where $\mathbf{h}_d$ is $(d+1)^{th}$ column of $\mathbf{H}$
5. $\mathbf{a}_k = [a_k a_{k-1} \cdots a_d \cdots a_{k-(N+\mu)}]^T$ and $a_i$ is iid
6. $n_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$
7. $\mathbf{c} = [c_0 c_1 \cdots c_{N}]$

**My guess is** 
Since $\mathbf{H},\sigma^2$ is known, therefore I compute $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ only once and then sweep $d\in[0,1,2,...,N+\mu]$, and compute $\mathbf{c}$ and $MSE$ for each value of $d$ and then choose one $d$ which yield minimum MSE.

But this is an exhaustive search and doesnt sound like a good idea.

Comment: How do the $c_i$ enter into the problem?

Comment: You are missing something in the problem statement.

Comment: I have included $y_k = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{r}_k$.

Comment: What space do they live in? Clearly you know what the problem is, but how would someone else guess? What is the distribution, etc, etc.?

Comment: Yes I missed specifying space for $c_i$. Distribution for $a_k$ is not important. I have mentioned that they are iid. Bullet-6 specifies distribution for $n_k$